# Extra "Space" at end of "If" Requirement AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, conditional-statements

My code works, except it is requiring and extra "Space" at the end to be placed in order for the button to activate? Any ideas? I obviously don't have the space at the end of the user names or passwords in the code. This happens on another frame as well where I have the user type in a web address, I have the conditional set as == "md.website.com" but it is requiring "md.website.com " (extra space at the end) in order for the button to activate.

This code is expecting "AB1234 " and "newuser " instead of "AB1234" "newuser" like I need and I am telling it... I'm sorry, I'm new to AS3 and learning ALL I can, this site rocks for all the help I've already gotten!

```
username_txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged3);
password_txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged3);

next_btn.enabled = false;
next_btn.alpha = .5;

function paramChanged3(event:TextEvent):void
{
    if (username_txt.text == "AB1234" && password_txt.text == "newuser" )
    {
        trace("go")
        next_btn2.enabled = true;
        next_btn2.alpha = 1;
        next_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlay_20)

    }
    else
    {
        next_btn2.enabled = false;
        next_btn2.alpha = .5;

    }
}

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlay_20(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` fires before the text field is actually updated.  Try using `Event.CHANGE` instead (or using two TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT callbacks and appending the input character with `event.text` within each).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why AS3 is requiring the extra space, but I removed the exact conditional, and just did a minimum character count. Of course the trainee can then type in anything as long as it matches the minimum requirement, but again, the actual usernames and passwords don't matter, its all simulation anyways, here is the code with the character count....

```
username_txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged3);
password_txt.addEventListener(TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT,paramChanged3);

next_btn.enabled = false;
next_btn.alpha = .5;

function paramChanged3(event:TextEvent):void
{
    if (username_txt.text != "" && username_txt.length >=5 && 
password_txt.text != "" && password_txt.length >=6)
    {
        trace("go")
        next_btn2.enabled = true;
        next_btn2.alpha = 1;
        next_btn2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlay_20)

    }
    else
    {
        next_btn2.enabled = false;
        next_btn2.alpha = .5;

    }
}

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlay_20(event:MouseEvent):void
{
gotoAndPlay(20);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution to relaxed constraints, but (strictly-speaking) it is not a solution to your problem, as stated.